# 80's or earlier first contact novel: scientists decode alien signal, only to discover the alien civilization is now long dead

Tags: story-identification, novel, first-contact

First contact novel read in the 80's where scientists decode alien signal only to discover the alien civilization is now long dead.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site. As this is a story identification question, you can also have a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info). Some more detail is likely to be helpful.

Comment: [*The Hercules Text*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hercules_Text) maybe?

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing that the book is James Gunn's "The Listeners" (1972).  The publication time frame works.  If you remember that the President in the book was black it's almost certain.

[image: book cover depicting a radio telescope]

A little elaboration from [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Listeners_(novel)):

> MacDonald reveals to Jeremiah that the static noise in the message included short bursts of pure sound ("dots"), similar to Morse code, but no "dashes." He believes Jeremiah is not just a fanatic but also an "honest man" who might change his views once he sees what The Project is doing. MacDonald tells Jeremiah that once the message in the static is decoded, he wants Jeremiah to come to The Project's headquarters in Puerto Rico to see the message first-hand.
>
> But The Reply also reveals that the Capellans died millennia ago and that the message Earth has been receiving is nothing more than an automated response from self-repairing machinery set in motion ages ago by the alien race.